# How move the program itself to another location in Python?

Tags: python, windows, move

How can I make the program verify if it's already on the targeted locations, and if not, move itself to another location?

Comment: I don't understand why you need to do that. won't it be better if you put the program in the correct location in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.path.abspath(__file__)` is the absolute path to the current module's (or main script's) present location, and [os.rename](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=os.rename#os.rename) is a way to move a file (not to a location where another file of the same name is already present, though; you'd have to `os.unlink` the latter first).

Comment: I've read in someplace that os.path.abspath(__file__) will not work properly with compiled scripts by py2exe, it's true?

Comment: @Shady, yes, `py2exe` changes the equation (you should mention in your Q if you're using `py2exe`!).  In that case, you can look at `sys.argv[0]` and if it doesn't include a directory you'll have to scan all directories on `os.environ['PATH']` to find it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `os.path.abspath(__file__)` that works with py2exe is `sys.executable`. if you say `filename = sys.executable.rsplit('\\',1)[1]`
filename would be your files name. this only works if you compile your programs with py2exe though since otherwise it will just display pythonw.exe or python.exe